# How to access Django app in docker container from another machine?

Tags: django, linux, docker, docker-compose

I am pretty new to Docker and Django. So what i did was, putty to a linux server and created a folder in the root directory and then using `django-admin startproject` I started a new project.
Now, since I am using putty for ssh terminal access, I will not be able to access a browser in the linux machine and then ping `127.0.0.1:8000` to see whether "congratulations!" screen by Django is visible or not.

So I assumed that the server might be running after `runserver` command. Then using docker I prepared a container in the linux machine where I have exposed port 9000. Also I cannot access this container since I cannot access the browser in the linux machine. Now, I have three questions below:

1.) How to access this docker container (inside the linux machine) using my windows machine? By this I mean, if I open up lets say google chrome browser in the windows machine, and enter some url:port, will I be able to see the "congratulations!" screen on my browser on windows?

2.) I am pretty confused with how this container network port and ip works (I mean how does host or any other pc access this docker container) I tried looking up on many documentation and youtube videos but I am very much confused. Because I know to make your website/app accessible to the external world we need domain name hosted on some cloud for which we need to pay, but how can docker do this for free? Might sound like a lame one, but please help me understand.

3.) How should my docker run command look like for accessing from my windows machine?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir /Django

WORKDIR /Django

ADD . /Django

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 9000

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
```

I am using the following command to build:

```
docker build -t myproj .
```

Please help clarifying my questions guy. I'll be forever grateful :)
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

When you run the container, you need a `docker run -p` option:

```sh
docker run -p 12345:9000 myproj
```

The second port number must match the port number the actual server process is listening on (in your case, the port argument to `./manage.py runserver`).  The first port number can be any port number that's not otherwise in use on the host system.

Then (up to networking and firewall constraints) another system can reach the container by using the host's IP address and the first port number; `http://my-dev-system.internal.example.com:12345`.  If you're calling from the host directly then these two systems are the same and in this special case you can use `http://localhost:12345`.

As an implementation detail the container happens to have its own IP address but you never need to look it up or use it.  (Among other problems, it is not accessible from other machines.)  From other systems' points of view a Docker-based process is indistinguishable from the process running directly on the host.  Docker doesn't address the problems of needing somewhere to host the application, coming up with a DNS name for the host, or other similar concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it without `EXPOSE 9000`, when you are exposing port it's visible only inside of a container and not to the outer world. After doing so, go to a browser and navigate to `<server_ip>:9000` and you will probably see the message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I tried doing it but it's telling me site took too long to respond. The linux machine has a password which I enter after putty opens the terminal. could this be the issue?